# Setting the delegate of a UITextField programatically from a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, delegates, uitextfield

I have a custom UIView which creates a UITextField as a subview while the application is running. I have been stuck on this for hours now, but cannot figure out how to create delegates to hide the keyboard and determine when the "done" button is pressed.  I'm still pretty new to iOS development, so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Post some relevant code so people can help.

Answer (score 2):

u can do this set

```
yourtextfieldname.delegate=self;
```

when u hide your keyboard.. then u can call that textfield and do this code...

```
 [txtfieldname resignFirstResponder];
```

or u can try this.. also

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [yourtextfieldname resignFirstResponder];
}
```

or best method

```
-(BOOL)textfieldshouldreturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
 [textField resignFirstResponder];
  }
```

Comment: you're missing `return YES;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using keyboard done button, set the delegate to the textfield

```
texfield.delegate = self;
```

then the below method will be called when done button is clicked

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField

{

   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;

}
```

If you are using done button on a toolbar created by you then add a target to the doneButton then call below method in the selector

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This may help you.First use UITextFieldDelegate and set 

 yourtextfield.delegate=self;

 Then use

 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {
    [yourtextfield resignFirstResponder];
  }
 // and also you can use this

 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
  {
      [yourtextfield resignFirstResponder];

       return YES;
  }
```